# How to instantiate a collection containing a complex generic type

Tags: java, generics

I'm using a third-party type defined like this:

```
abstract public class BaseRequest<T extends BaseRequest<T, R>, R extends BaseResponse>
```

I want to maintain a Queue of objects of this type and execute the requests periodically. I have the syntax down for the `execute` method:

```
protected <T extends BaseRequest<T, R>, R extends BaseResponse> void execute(T request, int tryCount) {
```

What I can't figure out how to do is instantiate a Queue that contains objects of this type. I'm not even sure if this is possible and would also settle for a `Queue<BaseRequest<?, ?>>` but then can't figure out how to cast to the type I need when I invoke `execute`.

I'm sure this has been answered before so apologies for that but I don't know how to phrase the question in a way where I can search for the answer.

Edit, here's a stripped-back version of the `execute` method showing why I require typed objects. The `thirdPartyApiWrapper` has an execute signature that includes a callback interface that I must implement with an anonymous inner class, which requires the types to be specified.

```
protected <T extends BaseRequest<T, R>, R extends BaseResponse> void execute(T request) {
    thirdPartyApiWrapper.execute(request, new Callback<T, R>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(BaseRequest request, BaseResponse response) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(BaseRequest request, IOException e) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: To *instantiate* a queue? `Queue<BaseRequest<?, ?>> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();`.

Comment: If I use `BaseRequest<?, ?>` then `execute(queue.remove())` doesn't compile. I either need a `Queue` containing the correct type or I need syntax that will cast it to the correct type.

Comment: Please show the `execute` method, specifically highlighting what about the type parameters of the `BaseRequest` needs to be known inside that method.

Comment: I've edited the question to show this.

Comment: What is the signature of `thirdPartyApiWrapper.execute`? Are the callback parameter types super-bounded?

Comment: `public <T extends BaseRequest<T, R>, R extends BaseResponse> void execute(T request, Callback<T, R> callback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting things into a `Queue<BaseRequest<?, ?>>`, you are losing the type information about the `BaseRequest`, as you know.

You can't recover this at the time you want to execute it, which you would need in order to pass in the callback.

I would suggest that you instead maintain a queue of instances which hold the `BaseRequest` and a compatible callback together:

```
class RequestAndCallback<T, R> {
  RequestAndCallback(BaseRequest<T, R> request, Callback<T, R> callback) {
    // store in fields.
  }

  void execute() {
    thirdPartyApiWrapper.execute(request, callback);
  }
}
```

Note that you don't need to know the type parameters in order to call `execute()` here: you can just have a `Queue<RequestAndCallback<?, ?>>`, and work your way through that.